# Issue with the ping_plugin on Nagios: no perfdata

Tags: plugins, ping, nagios

it is my first post and I don't speak english very well. Sorry in advance for the mistakes.
I am currently working on Nagios (nagios core 4.4.3) and I already installed some with no problem. Not this type of problem in fact. 
I am really stuck because of the ping plugin. When I am executing the command line with all the parameters it works very well but the 'automatic' works with Nagios doesn't work and I don't understand why.

I import the perfdata in a file and nothing is write, the $SERVICEOUTPUT$ looks like:

```
/bin/ping -n -U -w 10 -c 5 127.0.0.1
```

(127.0.0.1 is only for the example).

On the command line I write the following command and I get a good response:

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ping -H 127.0.0.1 -w 200.0,20% -c 500.0,80% -p 5
PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.05 ms|rta=0.052000ms;200.000000;500.000000;0.000000 pl=0%;20;80;0
```

The configuration of a service is like:

```
define service{
        use             my_service
        host_name       64594
        service_description     23349
        check_command   check_ping!127.0.0.1!200.0,20%!500.0,80%
        event_handler   event_handler
}
```

The configuration of the command:

```
define command{
        command_name    check_ping
        command_line    $USER1$/check_ping -H $ARG1$ -w $ARG2$ -c $ARG3$
        }
```

Thanks for your help, I would like to understand what is my mistake and why my ping services does not response.

Comment: Hello and welcome on Stackoverflow. Can you share with us your error message?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error came from the rights on /bin/ping. Hope it will be helpful.